# A binomial bandit v. a Gaussian process optimizer

Tags: regression, classification, gaussian-process

I am reading about multi-armed bandits for web optimization, and I have come across a couple of options, two of which are the [binomial bandit](http://www.economics.uci.edu/~ivan/asmb.874.pdf) and the [Gaussian process](http://las.ethz.ch/files/srinivas10gaussian.pdf) (an implementation [here](http://yelp.github.io/MOE/examples.html)). Am I correct in understanding that Gaussian processes are a way to model continuous-scale outputs, but the binomial bandit models only successes and failures? I am searching around for more examples of implementations and use cases, as the theory is well and good but ultimately I want to code this out. I have found the helpful gaussianprocess [website](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/) and I am looking at some of the MATLAB and Python code, but I would also appreciate any further examples.